# What does/could this Javascript notation { e => e } signify?

Tags: javascript

While troubleshooting a pdf-lib issue, I'm seeing this, to me unfamiliar, notation:

```
{ e => e }
```

- In the screenshot below I see that what I believe is a property called "dict" of an object called "catalog". The property "dict" is a *map* data structure.
- The double bracketed [[Entries]] notation is what I believe signifying a javascript internal property, and I believe may be read as similar to the `map.entries()` method. Thus, I would expect that what I see below it would be the output of the map entries, the map's key-pair values.
- Now, this is where things become foggy for me. The key's from this map seem to be numerical values 0-5, and its value are the aforementioned `{ e => e}`. The curly brackets are reminiscent of both objects and functions, and there seems to be an arrow function in there...?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What does/could this Javascript notation { e => e } signify?

It isn't JavaScript notation (e.g., syntax) in that context.¹ The display of objects in a console is not JavaScript syntax, though it's often closely related to it. That `{e => e}` (and `{e => t}` later) is just Chrome's console's way of showing you a `Map` entry where the key is an object whose constructor function is `e` and whose value is an object whose constructor function is also `e` (or `t` for the `{ e => t }` case).

You can see that here (in Chrome or others that use a similar display):

```js
class e {
}
const m = new Map();
m.set(new e(), new e());
console.log(m);
```

```html
Look in the real JavaScript console.
```

The real code presumably used a more meaningful constructor names than `e` and `t`, but has been minified.

---

¹ If `{ e => e}` appeared in JavaScript code where a statement was expected, it would be a block with an arrow function inside it that could never be called; if it appeared where an expression rather than a statement was expected, it'd be a syntax error.